# PAM custom way to get user

Tags: c, pam

my aim is to create custom PAM authentication module based on face recognition.

I am currently having some behavioral issues, because, the way I want this to work is:

- user boots the PC,
- camera runs and makes face recognition
- based on who is recognized, user is logged to a proper account.

there might be the issue, when user has multiple accounts, but let's assume this is not important.

So in this scenario I want to be able to determine user on my own, without user interaction. And the usual way to find out username in pam authentication module is by calling `pam_get_user`.

Is this possible to make it work the way I want, or the user have to pass it's username every time he/she wants to login?

Comment: My understanding is that PAM is used to verify (authenticate) that the user can present information that confirms that they are who they claim to be (or who the program decides they are claiming to be).  I don't think it has provision for deciding who they claim to be; that is effectively a given.  Thus I'm not sure you can do what you want.  But neither am I sure you can't — I may have forgotten something relevant.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think, you might be right. I am a PAM beginner though and I have never implemented any module. I thought it can be possible, because otherwise it would be quite a drawback, as biometric methods of authentication would be not so fully useful